# What is C++ preamble, and pre-post condition for get function

Tags: c++

I am beginner at C++, the homework ask us to document our code (preamble, and with the function's pre-post conditions). I am wondering how do they apply to my Student class?

In particular, what exactly is ***preamble*** mean? And for my get methods, what are the pre and post conditions? I have a feeling they are really for more advance's function (these who changes the value of the data)?

```
class Student:
{
public:
    // Constructor for the student class, require 4 parameters
    // In the order of string (first name), string (last name), 
    // integer (student ID), string (major)
    Student(string myFirstName, string myLastName, int myID, string myMajor)
    {
        firstName = myFirstName;
        lastName = myLastName;
        uid = myID;
        major = myMajor;
    }

    // Get function for the student's first name
    // Return the student's first name
    string getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }
    .....

private:
    string firstName; // Student's first name
    string lastName; // Student's last name
    int uid; // Student's ID number in a number format
    string major; // Student's major
};
```

Comment: Preamble is understoud as the constructor initializer list and means written out "Preliminary Material", my personal suggestion to homework, ask the guys who teach it, there is nothing better than letting them explain it directly to you, they might have a more specific description and only from them you can source the expectations for delivering results

Comment: It is spring break, the teacher doesn't want to answer my emails :( (he is off I suppose)...

Comment: That's a sign of a bad teacher. Solution: Get a different teacher.

Comment: About your other question about the post conditions and pre conditions of your "get" methods, pre condition is that they have been initialized, if you add another "Constructor" with no arguments but blank initialization you can eliminate the pre condition, i have found a good link for you while googling for it, [Some Random PPT](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/supplements/chapt01.ppt)

Comment: Currently the Class description is missing, just as side note, if you become a coder i recommend to you to read alot, it is really the key to "not waste time" some of our old school programmers call this the "RTFM" ;-)

Comment: @Casey, I think that a teacher is entitled to some vacation. Are you happy when your boss complains that you are not responding to e-mail when on vacation?

Comment: @Hiemstra: It's a sign if the teacher assigns work over spring break and then refuses to do any work themselves, e.g. answer questions, grade papers, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

preamble is a source code comment appearing before the function that documents its behaviour, normally in a way that a tool like doxygen can automatically create useful documentation from it.

A good policy for documentation is to **document everything that isn't obvious and nothing that is**.  On that basis, I'd say your getXXX() have no pre- or post-conditions worth documenting.  Something like "must be called on a properly constructed object" is just a waste of the reader's time, as is a post-condition like "the caller will have received a copy of the student-specific XXX data".  Don't do it!  The question of whether the values can legally be empty strings is one for the constructor (or may even be a class invariant - something the class maintains as true, for instance by having the constructor throw if a value is empty and by not providing functions that wipe out the values), not for the `get` function documentation.

Similarly, your comments for firstName, lastName and major add absolutely no value, but your comment for `uid` does add value - documenting a requirement for a string format!  From that I can tell you've made a mistake, as the field is an `int`, and there's something to investigate and correct.  But more generally, say you had a string type - a comment might usefully communicate some restrictions on the format of the id, say that these ids relate to some other API or source, give an example etc.

More generally, pre-conditions aren't only for mutator (data changing) functions.  For example, a function `day_for_date(int year, int month, int day)` that tells you what day of the week a particular date falls on may have a pre-condition that year/month/day does actually describe say a valid date between 1000 and 3000 A.D..  That's nasty, but it means if you've already checked that somewhere the function call doesn't waste time re-verifying it.  In Defensive Programming style (which IMHO tends to make for more robust code) you would tend not to make that a precondition; instead, accept redundant verification as a net win (though you may provide explicit options to disable it if the caller needs the performance), and document an exception or error outcome should the date not meet expectations.  The difference is that a precondition is something the caller must guarantee for the function to operate as documented, where-as in defensive programming you generally let the caller try something and have a defined/documented manageable behaviour - a change in state, return value or error reported in a predictable way - for as broad a range of prior states and inputs as is practical.

Post-conditions only make sense for mutators: whatever could be asserted about the state after the call to a non-mutating accessor must have been true beforehand - it might be a class invariant.

Comment: I would recommend to also make note of the obvious, at the beginning teachers tend to get the scope of the student, excluding stuff will give the impression that he/she is overlooking the simple things but your answer is pretty good, better than serving him everything on a plate

Comment: It is meant to be an int, I actually wrote the wrong comment :( Really careless. But I sort of agree with you, since the variable name is about as clear they can get. I don't know what is there to really write (as comment).

Comment: I think I sort of get what you mean in the pre-condition and post-condition meaning. Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend documenting every class and method. They add comments to give a commentary on the rest of the code.That way when you come back in a years time, something that you now find obvious might not appear to be obvious later on to to different people.

Comment: OliverStutz: I agree the teacher may expect that, but definitely it's not a good habit and has no place in professional standard code.  George: you're welcome!  @Ed: when someone comes back years later, it's even more important that they can quickly understand the functionality - 100% redundant comments just waste the time they could be spending on the tricky bits.  As George says, picking good variable names goes a long way to making code self documenting; of course good function and type names are equally important.

Comment: @OliverStutz - I agree that chosing good variable names is a very good idea. But in the future a little commentary with the code helps. It does not take long and I find it helps the thought process as well.

Comment: @JamesKanze - I write both at the same time. Perhaps my english could have been a little better.

Answer (score 1):

If this is homework, I **strongly** suggest you ask this question in class as most teachers have some particular requirements that an online community is unlikely to know about (unless you tell us ;-).  That being said, we might be able to get you started in the right direction.

The *preamble* is usually a (short) description of what a particular file, class or function does.

The *pre-conditions* are the requirements on the arguments passed by the caller, as well as the program state prior to the call.  They establish under what conditions the function will produce the correct results.  For instance, you may request that the first and last names in your example class constructor are non-empty.

A *post-condition* usually documents side-effects applied by a function.  For instance,

```
class Person
{
public:
    std::string firstName () const;

    // post-condition: firstName() returns 'name'.
    void setFirstName (std::string name);
};
```

The wikipedia articles on [pre-conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondition) and [post-conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcondition) provide more elaborate descriptions.

Comment: The thing is that I don't recall she said anything about preamble, at first I thought it is the initialization of the variable on the same line as the constructor. I am going to take a deeper read on the link!

Comment: In general, the preamble to something is just a descriptive piece of text that precedes the described item.  In the case of a C++ function, that would be a comment that describes the function's role or purpose.